# Performance characteristics of SortedSet

Tags: scala

I want to keep items in a list that is sorted for quick access. Addition/retrieval performance is important, but I can't find any information on performance characteristics for `SortedSet`: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

Is `SortedSet` the optimal class to use for speedy addition/retrieval when my items are sorted?

Comment: i'm guessing your elements are unique if you're looking at sets?

Comment: Perhaps more details on your use case would enable more elaborate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default implementation of `SortedSet` in Scala 2.12 uses a `TreeSet`:

```
scala> val s = scala.collection.SortedSet(3, 5, 1)
s: scala.collection.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(1, 3, 5)
```

Internally, a `TreeSet` is implemented using a [Red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). This means that both search and insertion operations will be in `O(log(n))`. If this is "speedy" enough really depends on the characteristics of your application, in which I don't know enough to supply a broader answer.

For more details on collection performance, [this blog post by Li Haoyi is a great place to start](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html)